# How to delete redundant elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

We want to delete redundant elements of a list, we  consider that the tuples  `{a,b}` and `{b,a}` are equivalent.

**Input :** {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 4}}

**Desired Output :** {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4}}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort] @ {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 4}}
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
> ```

```
DeleteDuplicates[{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1,  4}}, 
   Sort @ # == Sort @ #2 &]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
alist = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 4}}

Union@(Sort /@ alist)
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}